# Version Control with Jaspersoft Server Queries / Input Controls

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver, jaspersoft-studio

As anyone who has used Jasper Reports would know, a single report in Studio does not always encapsulate everything that a report is.  There are Input Controls that can exist outside of the report as well as Queries that may be responsible for populating the controls.

Jaspersoft does not make it easy to obtain and version the entities that exist outside of the normal report JRXML files that you design in Studio.  As of now, the only way I've been able to even somewhat accomplish this is like so:

1. Create Query and Input Control in DEV environment
2. Export the ZIP file that Jasper generates for said Query and Control
3. Extract the files and blow away or hand-modify the connection information in the Data Source, because Jasper packages *everything* associated with an item.
4. Add necessary files to SCM.
5. ZIP files up.
6. Import ZIP file in to QA environment, and then Staging, and so on.

While this can be *somewhat* automated, it seems like anyone working with Jasper has to jump through hoops to actually version their reports.  Am I missing something, or is this really just the nature of things in this space?

Comment: This is pretty similar to what I do except I actually package all reports/input controls/resources/datasources etc. used in the export.zip and store these as a single zip unit in our SCM. I was hoping when Jaspersoft moved to Studio, which is based on Eclipse, that everything could be individually managed in SCM but as you say apparently not.

Comment: 3 years later and this is the only way I can find on how to store everything in SCM. How has this worked for everyone that has been doing this for awhile?